# Multiples DataSources en Spring Boot de forma dinamica

Tags: spring, jpa

Tengo desarrollado un sistema el cual utilizan muchos clientes, el problema que tengo es que tengo un WAR por cada uno, eso funcionaba hasta que ya pase los 15 clientes y tiene vistas a futuro que vana  ser muchos mas.
Como solucion queria saber si se puede configurar de alguna forma mi proyecto para que se concecte de manera dinamica a un Datasource dependiendo del cliente (parámetro) o saber que solucion puedo llegar a tenes respecto a ello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot soporta múltiples datasources en el mismo contexto.
Deberás configurar como @Bean los N Datasource, cada una con sus propiedades (url, user, pass..).
Posteriormente, deberás configurar dinámicamente la capa de @Repository para que utilice un datasource u otro, en función (por ejemplo) del usuario logado, ya que le habrás asociado a cada usuario al cliente al que pertenece y puede inferir el repo a utilizar.

Un saludo

Comment: O sea, deberia hacer una conexion por defecto en la que tengo el usuario, luego configurar el resto, o depenediendo de cada servicio apunto a diferentes datasource?